# Missing template on Devise Registration Form (sign up)

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to understand as to who I get

```
Template is missing

Missing template devise/registrations/create, devise/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "C:/project/app/views" * "C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/views"
```

if I try to send the registration information via :remote => true.

As far as I understand, using remote true will ensure that the form is sent with an ajax post, but once I hit submit I see that the server returns the missing template error.

I read somewhere that the registration controller is already using respond_with (I see in the code) which means that it should respond to the ajax.

Can someone clarify that or if I am missing a piece in the puzzle?

Comment: Try adding the create.js file in the devise registration folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file called create.js in the devise registration folder.